# How to calculate hexadecimal xor (^) from shell?

Tags: shell, hex, calculator

Unfortunately bc and calc don't support xor.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo $(( 0xA ^ 0xF ))
```

Or if you want the answer in hex:

```
printf '0x%X\n' $(( 0xA ^ 0xF ))
```

On a side note, `calc(1)` **does** support `xor` as a function:

```
$ calc
base(16)
    0xa
xor(0x22, 0x33)
    0x11
```

Comment: In case your numbers are binary: `printf '0x%X\n' $(( 2#1010 ^ 2#1111 ))`

Answer (score 23):

With any POSIX shell:

```
$ printf '%#x\n' "$((0x11 ^ 0x22))"
0x33
```

Comment: `%#x` works in C too, nice!

Comment: @StevenPenny, note that one difference with `0x%x` is that it gives `0` instead of `0x0` for 0.

Answer (score 14):

gdb has powerful expression calculator:

```
gdb -q -ex 'print/x 0xA ^ 0xF' -ex q
```

A shell function:

```
calc_gdb() { gdb -q -ex "print/x $*" -ex q;}
calc_gdb 0xA ^ 0xF

$1 = 0x5
```

Comment: Amusing, but it seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut!

Comment: Useful for the more general case of evaluating expressions, but not for XOR

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to do that in bc:

```
echo 'xor(10,15)' | bc -l logic.bc
```

Or in hex:

```
echo 'obase=16;ibase=16; xor(AA,FF)' | bc -l logic.bc
```

Using the [logic file from here](http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/index.html#logic).

Just do `wget http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/code/logic.bc` to get it.

Comment: Wow, that site is the `bc(1)` geek's heaven. :) Thank you for the link.

Comment: My version of "bc" doesn't seem to have the XOR function and just says: `Runtime error (func=(main), adr=51): Function xor not defined.`

Comment: @slacy did you get the `logic.bc` file referenced there?  That is what defines `xor` it seems

Comment: The functions in http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/code/logic.bc do work with GNU bc but do not work with macOS bc  (bc 4.0.2, Gavin D. Howard and contributors) .
The problem is in the precedence between boolean NOT (!) and Modulus (%). ! has the precedence in macOS bc but in GNU bc % has the precedence over !.